# Como conseguir carregar esses dados criados em uma tela de edição

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Seguinte, eu tenho essa tela de cadastro onde clicando no botão "+" vai adicionar inputs tipo texto (conforme codigo em anexo)
Meu problema é que essa criação é dinamica, a pessoa pode adicionar tanto 1, quando 2,3,4..ou seja N.
vou salvar esse dados e preciso que na hora de editar, consiga montar essa mesma estrutura. Ou seja, vai carregar todos os inputs de texto criados na tela de adição.
Eu não sei como fazer trazer essas informações de forma dinamica.
Estou aplicando angular v1 no projeto, estou usando para fazer a integração com o backend.
Então, gostaria de uma solução mais focada pro angular.
Exite uma forma de fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Defina uma variável que vai guardar os valores no controller e um counter:

```
$scope.x = [];
$scope.counter = 0;
```

Agora você precisa de colocar `ng-model` nos inputs. Para isso, você precisa criar o html de forma dinâmica por ser um array que vai ter um counter dinêmico, e aí entra o `$compile`, documentação aqui: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Basicamente funciona assim:

```
// cria o input
var input = '<div class="itens"><div id="radios"><input type="radio" disabled style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" value="teste" name="data"><input type="text" value="" class="form-control radio-alinha text" placeholder="Adicionar Alternativa" ng-model="x[' + $scope.counter + ']"><a href="#" class="del"><span class= "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></div></div>';
//compila e coloca no escopo
var compile = $compile(input)($scope);
```

Aí a var input fica renderizada. Não esquece de aumentar o counter no final: `counter++`